# wait(NULL) is not waiting till forked process is finished

Tags: c, linux, fork, wait, waitpid

This is the function that executes commands in a child process using system(). But once command completes execution it is expected to stop. Yet, on running ps command, I find new a.out process running. The program was supposed to wait for child to complete.

```
    void execute(char **argv)
    {
      if(fork() == 0)
      {
         if (argv[1] == NULL)
         {
           system(argv[0]);
         }
         else
         {
           char tmp[1024] ; 
           *(tmp+0) = '\0';
           strcat(tmp,*argv++);
           while(*argv !=NULL)
           {
              strcat(tmp," ");
              strcat(tmp,*argv++);
           }
           system(tmp);
         }
     }
    else
    {
        printf("\nWaiting\n");
        wait(0);
        printf("\nWaiting Complete\n");
    }
  }
```

The output for following is of this kind

```
SillyShell> ps

Waiting
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7520 tty2     00:00:00 bash
 7919 tty2     00:00:00 a.out
 7923 tty2     00:00:00 a.out
 7926 tty2     00:00:00 a.out
 7927 tty2     00:00:00 sh
 7928 tty2     00:00:00 ps
SillyShell>
```

This is the edited code as one of solution. Once the command with "&" is used after that again wait stops waiting for any process

```
            void execute(char **argv)
            {
                pid_t pid;
                int countArg = 0;
                char** tmp = argv;
                while(*argv !=NULL)
                {
                        *argv++;
                        countArg++;
                }
                argv = tmp;
                //printf("%s",argv[countArg-1]);

                int flg = 0;
                if(strcmp(argv[countArg-1], "&") == 0)
                {
                    //printf("Running in Background\n");
                    flg = 1;
                    argv[countArg-1] = NULL;
                }

                if((pid=fork()) < 0)
                {
                    printf("Could not create child process");
                    exit(1);
                }
                else if(pid == 0)
                {
                    if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0)
                    {
                        printf("Could not execute command");
                        exit(2);
                    }
                else
                {
                    if(flg==1)
                        exit(0);
                }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(flg == 1)
                    {
                        printf("PID=%d Running in background\n",pid);
                        flg=0;
                    fflush(stdin);
                        return;
                    }
                else
                {

                    printf("Waiting %s %d",*argv,pid);
                    wait(NULL);
                    printf("--wait complete");
                }
                }
            }
```

Output

```
        Waiting clear 6532--wait completeSillyShell> ls
        a.out  blockchain  key.pem  task1.c  task3.c  wait.c
        bash   fork.c      OpenMP   task2.c  task4.c
        Waiting ls 6535--wait completeSillyShell> ps &
        PID=6537 Running in background
        SillyShell>    PID TTY          TIME CMD
        6406 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
        6531 pts/1    00:00:00 a.out
        6537 pts/1    00:00:00 ps

        SillyShell> ps
        Waiting ps 6538--wait completeSillyShell>    PID TTY          TIME CMD
        6406 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
        6531 pts/1    00:00:00 a.out
        6538 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: Where's the code that stops the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child process never *exits!* When the `system` function is done, then the child process will just continue. You need to explicitly `exit` it.

Or do like most shell-like implementations do and use [the `exec` family of function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) to execute the command instead of `system`. The `exec` functions replace the process with the executed program, and never returns (unless there's an error). When the executed program terminates, that terminates the process as well.

Comment: Hey, got it. I explicitly mentioned pid using funtion waitpid(). It all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly mentioning pid using waitpid(pid, status, option) solved all the issues.